# g++-6 errors on shadowed template parameters while g++-5 does not

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, g++, shadow

Take the following example:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T, template <class T> class Container>
std::vector<T> To_Vector(Container<T> const& c){
  return std::vector<T>( c.begin(), c.end() );
}

int main(){}
```

With `g++-5`, it compiles without errors:

```
g++-5 -o main main.cpp
```

With `g++-6` is fails to compile:

```
g++-6 -o main main.cpp
main.cpp:4:33: error: declaration of template parameter ‘T’ shadows template parameter
 template <typename T, template <class T> class Container>
                                 ^~~~~
main.cpp:4:11: note: template parameter ‘T’ declared here
 template <typename T, template <class T> class Container>
```

Is the compiler wrong?  Is my code wrong?
Why does  `g++-5` compile this code while `g++-6` does not?

---

```
g++-5 --version    
g++-5 (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04) 5.4.1 20160904
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

---

```
g++-6 --version
g++-6 (Ubuntu 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~14.04) 6.2.0 20160901
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: @skypjack Ok, so I should leave out the 'T' in <class T>, because just <class> builds for me.

Comment: It's a valid and working solution. That `T` is useless in your example, isn't it?

Comment: @skypjack You're right.  I must have been confused in thinking that the container type name had to be specialized on type T, but that happens on the actual parameters.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, the template parameter list of the function only mentions a template class having a parameter list with size 1. The name of the parameter is useless in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour of g++6 is correct because according to the standard:

> A *template-parameter* shall not be redeclared within its scope (including nested scopes). A *template-parameter* shall not have the same name as the template name.

The scope of `T` begins right after its declaration, so it extends into the following template template parameter, which redeclares `T` as a template parameter, therefore this rule is violated.

I imagine the change between g++5 and g++6 was due to fixing some bug report around a similar issue.

Comment: Why this works instead? `template <template <class T> class Container, typename T>
`. Are they different scopes being part of different parameter lists?

Comment: @skypjack the first `T`'s scope does not extend to the rest of the template parameter list , so the second `T` does not hide it.